# database reading issue with Java and php

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, applet

Below is the Java code, trying to connect to a mysql database using php script, the                           connection is established but there is a problem in reading and inserting tables.
Any recommendation is greatly appreciate it, Both Java and php codes are given :

```
    package tc21reserve;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class TC21Create extends javax.swing.JApplet {


        @Override
        public void init() {

            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TC21Create.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TC21Create.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TC21Create.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TC21Create.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the applet */
            try {
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        initComponents();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
         * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
         * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jComboBox3 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jComboBox4 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

            jLabel1.setText("New Reservation");

            jLabel2.setText("License #: ");

            jLabel3.setText("Site: ");

            jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Garage A", "Garage B" }));

            jLabel4.setText("Floor:");

            jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2" }));

            jLabel5.setText("Spot:");

            jComboBox3.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210" }));

            jLabel6.setText("Reservation Date(MM/DD/YYYY):");

            jLabel7.setText("Duration:");

            jComboBox4.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Hourly", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", " " }));

            jLabel8.setText("Credit Card:");

            jLabel9.setText("Expiration Date(MM/YYYY):");

            jButton1.setText("Submit");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton2.setText("Clear");

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(jSeparator1))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(159, 159, 159)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField2))
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 67, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addComponent(jLabel7))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jComboBox3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addComponent(jComboBox4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addGap(14, 14, 14))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 92, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addComponent(jButton2))
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19))
            );
        }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
     try {
                // open a connection to the site
            Dsend();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

        }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

        // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox3;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
        private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
        // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables

    public void Dsend() throws Exception {
    URL hp = new URL("http://www.luxuryparking.comeze.com/DBinput.php"); 

    HttpURLConnection hpCon = (HttpURLConnection) hp.openConnection();
    hpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    hpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     hpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");         
          hpCon.setUseCaches (false);
          hpCon.setDoOutput(true);

                // important: get output stream before input stream
        DataOutputStream ps = new DataOutputStream (hpCon.getOutputStream());
        ps.writeBytes("license=" + URLEncoder.encode(jTextField1.getText(), "UTF-8"));


        hpCon.getInputStream();`enter code here`

        // close the print stream
        ps.flush ();
          ps.close ();
        } }
// Java code Done
// And below is the php script :
    <?php

    // Connects to your Database
    $host="mysql17.000webhost.com"; // Host name
    $username="username"; // Mysql username
    $password="password"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="a4335408_data1"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="Reservation"; // Table name

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=a4335408_data1", $username, $password);

    for each ($_POST as $key =&gt; $value) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'license':
                $license = $value;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    $license=$_POST['license'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Reservation (LicensePlate) VALUES (:license)";

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $q->execute(array(':license'=>$license));

    ?>
```

Comment: check this line `for each ($_POST as $key =&gt; $value) {`

Comment: couldn't all these similar variables be declared in a loop?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your database username & password. Go and change it RIGHT NOW before my associates arrive and wreak havoc.

Comment: *"And below is the php script :"*  Show the HTML as it arrives in the browser.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (e.g. 2 labels rather than 9, don't set the PLAF..).